# Why bluetooth audio stops, then starts again (log file clearly shows the two states)

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 20.04, bluez, blueman

My system is Lenovo G50 with Ubuntu 20.04 64bit (8Gb RAM).

After a fresh install of the OS I had bluetooth issue like always.

This time I somehow managed to get the bt mouse and the bt headphones to work with my system by  means of installing bluez.

Here's some information about the devices:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Z50-75 [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1058:1042 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements SE Portable (WDBPCK)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0c45:6513 Microdia Lenovo EasyCamera
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0781:556b SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Edge
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The mouse is working. It also seems that the audio quality is good because the headphones stay in high-quality mode instead of switching to headset mode.

But I get sound interruptions: the sounds comes out for some tens of seconds, then the sound stops, while the playback continues, then the sound comes again, after some tens of seconds.

And that repeats again and again.

I found this useful command

```
sudo btmon
```

that let me log the bluetooth, so I got a clear debugging log of the two states, that you can read below:

many numeric data while the sounds is working, and other debug info during the period of time the playback goes on and the sounds is not present.

(note that, I reported just few data from each of the two sections, which in fact are longer)

Can you envise the cause, and how to avoid what is happening that stops the sound?

```
 ACL Data TX: Handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 820              #7310 [hci0] 57.301029
< ACL Data TX: Handle 1 flags 0x01 dlen 44               #7311 [hci0] 57.301060
      Channel: 67 len 860 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        80 60 ed 1d 09 04 c5 ab 00 00 00 01 0b 9c bd 20  .`............. 
        cc e0 b8 41 00 00 97 41 00 00 c2 4e 26 2a 4c d1  ...A...A...N&*L.
        96 ba 14 20 7d 3b 7c bc d8 ad dc d5 3a 64 c5 41  ... };|.....:d.A
        05 23 9f c1 26 bb c3 bd f2 a2 bb 2d dc 33 22 b6  .#..&......-.3".
        5a 54 33 56 6b 2c a0 15 9e 4b 95 be 04 ab 7a 4a  ZT3Vk,...K....zJ
        22 65 60 c2 6c 1d 70 4b 67 53 9c bd 20 49 f0 c7  "e`.l.pKgS.. I..
        52 00 00 a7 41 00 00 7f c2 a7 08 74 66 1e d8 7d  R...A......tf..}
        25 d5 a4 8d d9 d4 5b 7c 19 4e 9b 49 d8 be ca 67  %.....[|.N.I...g
        d4 b4 b1 a1 b8 bc ca 8c 91 15 24 59 c0 bc 53 7f  ..........$Y..S.
        a8 dc 1a c3 e1 51 63 bc d9 32 b4 99 69 a6 2e 7d  .....Qc..2..i..}
        12 51 3b 74 ea 63 a8 9c bd 20 da f0 c8 41 00 00  .Q;t.c... ...A..
        a7 40 00 00 5b 3e 46 4a 39 3e ca 32 67 2e b6 bb  .@..[>FJ9>.2g...
        ad b6 1d 43 c3 d1 21 5b 8e 44 bf ab 74 45 e6 b4  ...C..![.D..tE..
        7c 39 df 2c 56 c1 a0 a3 49 41 b6 61 72 b2 4d 98  |9.,V...IA.ar.M.
        83 c9 3e 42 6b 15 3b be 7f 51 36 44 aa bd 40 c3  ..>Bk.;..Q6D..@.
        ab bd 30 2b 9c bd 20 62 d0 b7 51 00 00 a7 51 00  ..0+.. b..Q...Q.
        00 78 13 58 ba 02 c3 c3 32 4c c3 b3 d3 d4 ca 86  .x.X....2L......
        34 c1 b3 2f 33 9f 33 51 2c d2 4c 9f 54 d7 4a a9  4../3.3Q,.L.T.J.
        1b 36 29 98 53 1f 20 b4 9b 6c 98 7b 61 9b d8 3f  .6).S. ..l.{a..?
        31 90 d9 5c 59 64 21 86 11 6e 5a bf da 96 c3 63  1..\Yd!..nZ....c
        82 9c bd 20 02 d8 b8 41 00 00 a7 42 00 00 7d ca  ... ...A...B..}.
        9b 61 61 33 49 9e 90 46 56 bd 7d 1d d2 53 12 da  .aa3I..FV.}..S..
        40 3d 4c c2 ba cc b8 3b 40 bb ad b6 13 2c 47 45  @=L....;@....,GE
        ae 45 77 46 5a bb dd ba 5a 43 e3 31 b8 aa af d0  .EwFZ...ZC.1....
        a7 4d 77 a4 cc bd 84 e1 5f 42 57 9d c0 aa 9c bd  .Mw....._BW.....
        20 4e e8 c7 41 00 00 a7 31 00 00 3f dd bf 1d 5a   N..A...1..?...Z
        84 bf 16 9f b4 a7 ee c0 40 aa 59 8e a9 bb 9e 76  ........@.Y....v
        a5 dc da 7d 2a 64 22 61 56 1d 94 50 eb 2b e0 67  ...}*d"aV..P.+.g
        8e c4 91 82 65 cc 26 6f cd 43 68 84 b4 3c 54 9d  ....e.&o.Ch..<T.
        c8 41 ad b2 38 b5 0d 8a 55 25 a9 9c bd 20 c5 b0  .A..8...U%... ..
        b8 41 00 00 a7 41 00 00 11 b8 cc e3 41 c0 63 32  .A...A......A.c2
        b9 35 49 da bf de 21 b4 98 8e a1 24 ce 76 4e 65  .5I...!....$.vNe
        ee 26 5b 42 4b b6 c5 a1 1d 4a d4 cc 4e 3a c7 2d  .&[BK....J..N:.-
        99 ba a7 2c 9f 4e ab 44 60 b6 b3 bc 55 c6 dc b3  ...,.N.D`...U...
        98 c3 3f 5b 90 4e 9e 51 9c bd 20 15 e8 b8 51 00  ..?[.N.Q.. ...Q.
        00 a7 41 00 00 56 a5 bd 28 86 4d 51 b1 78 9d d3  ..A..V..(.MQ.x..
        c1 1b d5 48 44 42 1c bd 46 a1 4c bc 44 c1 b9 1f  ...HDB..F.L.D...
        2c 6d 45 9e cd 78 36 53 1c ba 52 5e 43 d7 2a 3f  ,mE..x6S..R^C.*?
        32 b9 4a 2f ba 73 36 38 c4 96 d2 e2 55 79 26 49  2.J/.s68....Uy&I
        9b 1a e1 c3 5b 9c bd 20 ee a0 b8 51 00 00 a7 42  ....[.. ...Q...B
        00 00 24 11 c3 89 b5 da 29 68 f3 41 a6 13 a4 3d  ..$.....)h.A...=
        33 eb 64 c1 55 1b 66 3d 6c 53 59 d1 ad 4d 3e ae  3.d.U.f=lSY..M>.
        25 4d 48 46 3e b4 7d 1e 4a b2 5d ce 40 1a 7b ba  %MHF>.}.J.].@.{.
        3f bd 97 3e 42 25 db 42 40 ce ae ae 26 8e 38 c6  ?..>B%.B@...&.8.
        b8 73 9c bd 20 b8 d4 b8 51 00 00 a6 52 00 00 3b  .s.. ...Q...R..;
        53 63 d5 9d 9f 4d 8d a4 46 26 c5 8c 30 9a 2d da  Sc...M..F&..0.-.
        cc c6 ec f1 b4 de 1b 7a 45 49 51 35 a1 5a a1 36  .......zEIQ5.Z.6
        54 48 b1 89 30 a8 59 8f bd 23 21 5a 2d b3 aa 43  TH..0.Y..#!Z-..C
        ca 5a e2 a7 c9 c7 23 b7 ce 1d 6b 5f 9a b2 04 9c  .Z....#...k_....
        bd 20 84 f8 b8 51 00 00 a7 40 00 00 7b e2 d6 bd  . ...Q...@..{...
        65 9e d5 bd 17 da 4e 63 2d 1e 3f 10 8f d1 bb 69  e.....Nc-.?....i
        c4 a1 a3 25 a2 f9 96 c4 8e 29 cb 42 a6 3d e2 93  ...%.....).B.=..
        c9 c1 44 3b a6 b9 b3 4c 63 35 ae 3b a9 cd e0 c1  ..D;...Lc5.;....
        9f 9d d2 b2 3e 49 c4 bc 1b ba 43 4d              ....>I....CM    
@ RAW Open: blueman-manager version 2.22                     {0x0005} 57.971315
@ RAW Close: blueman-manager                                 {0x0005} 57.971348
< HCI Command: Read RSSI (0x05|0x0005) plen 2            #7312 [hci0] 57.974078
        Handle: 1
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7              #7313 [hci0] 57.975277
      Read RSSI (0x05|0x0005) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 1
        RSSI: -16 dBm (0xf0)
< HCI Command: Read Link Quality (0x05|0x0003) plen 2    #7314 [hci0] 57.975480
        Handle: 1
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7              #7315 [hci0] 57.977276
      Read Link Quality (0x05|0x0003) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 1
        Link quality: 0x00
< HCI Command: Read Transmit Pow.. (0x03|0x002d) plen 3  #7316 [hci0] 57.977477
        Handle: 1
        Type: Current Transmit Power Level (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7              #7317 [hci0] 57.978230
      Read Transmit Power Level (0x03|0x002d) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 1
        TX power: 0 dbm (0x00)
@ RAW Open: blueman-manager version 2.22                     {0x0005} 58.971747
@ RAW Close: blueman-manager                                 {0x0005} 58.971784
< HCI Command: Read RSSI (0x05|0x0005) plen 2            #7318 [hci0] 58.974693
        Handle: 1
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7              #7319 [hci0] 58.976293
      Read RSSI (0x05|0x0005) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 1
        RSSI: -8 dBm (0xf8)
< HCI Command: Read Link Quality (0x05|0x0003) plen 2    #7320 [hci0] 58.976543
        Handle: 1
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7              #7321 [hci0] 58.977238
      Read Link Quality (0x05|0x0003) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 1
        Link quality: 0x00
< HCI Command: Read Transmit Pow.. (0x03|0x002d) plen 3  #7322 [hci0] 58.977396
        Handle: 1
        Type: Current Transmit Power Level (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7              #7323 [hci0] 58.978219
      Read Transmit Power Level (0x03|0x002d) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 1
        TX power: 0 dbm (0x00)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I added the command output in text, thanks